# How to extract values from Bing Speech API output

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the Bing Speech API (with Javascript - REST API) and as a result get something like this:

```
[{ 
  "lexical":"gerson de laudos médicos por meio do reconhecimento automático",
  "display":"gerson de laudos por meio do reconhecimento automático",
  "inverseNormalization":null,
  "maskedInverseNormalization":null,
  "transcript":"gerson de laudos por meio do reconhecimento automático",
  "confidence":0.7618318
}]
```

How do I get the result is just what is transcribed? For example, I would like to output only was the text: "gerson de laudos médicos por meio do reconhecimento automático"

Comment: One question at a time please. If you want multiple things ask multiple questions. And try to make them more precise, right now it is not quite clear what are you asking.

Comment: I left only a question now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.parse to get the results,

For ex : JSON.parse(results.d).transcript, here results.d is the resultant json data you got from Bing API & transcript

Hope that helps, let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: I was contact with Microsoft, and told me that the code in JavaScript Bing Speech API has no date to launch an SDK in Javascript.

So for now, I try not to call the result of transcription by .JSONbecause this API in JavaScript does not work well.

Answer (score 0):

I said these lines:

`lexical: r.lexical,
display: r.name,
inverseNormalization: null,
maskedInverseNormalization: null,`

Now to take [{"transcript":" and "}], I will use Javascript.